# Putty's terminal freezes during windows share accessing just after resuming VM after suspending

Tags: suspend, cifs, oracle-linux, vmware-workstation

1. My system is Oracle Linux 7.4 VM on VMWare Workstation 14
2. I have the next record in my `/etc/fstab`:

`//someip/someshare /mnt/temp cifs rw,user=someuser,password=somepassword 0 0`

3. After the system started I could access my windows share
4. After pausing VM and resuming it:

   1) accessing `/mnt/temp` hangs Putty's terminal

   2) `unmount /mnt/temp` command hangs Putty's terminal

   3) System reboots in 14 minutes

How to workaround this problem?

Is it possible to automatically unmount windows share before Sleep and mount it again after Awaking?

Or, maybe forcefully umount it after Awaiking and mount again?

Or, maybe there's a problem with my mounting options in `/etc/fstab`?

[image]